# dropping unused levels ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, pie-chart

I have some data and I would like to make some pie chart. Here some dummy data

```
data = data.frame(variables = c("var1", "var1", "var1", 
                                "var2", "var2", "var2", 
                                "var3", "var3", "var3"),
                  values = c("A", "B", "C",
                             "D", "E", "F",
                             "G", "H", "J"),
                  freq = c(.2,.2,.6,
                           .3,.4,.3,
                           .25,.25,.5))
```

Basically 3 variables with their respective levels and their frequency. It is important to note that the values do not apply to all the variables, ie. variables do not share levels.
I used this code to produce the chart:

```
data %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(x = values, y = freq, fill = values), stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar()+
  facet_grid(~variables)+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

which makes this graph:

[image: graph]

as you can see the chart displays the levels for all the variables, even when they are not applicable. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Do you mean `data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = freq, fill = values)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y") +
  facet_grid(~ variables)`?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much